# In Pandas Python how do i replace Characters in String column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-cleaning

```
data = pd.read_json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OMS1996/DAV-5400/master/Books.json')
data= data.transpose()
data=data[["Title","Authors","Publisher","Language","Pages"]]
data
```

This is the result of the code above

```
        Title               Authors                      Publisher                  Language      Pages
Book1   David Copperfield   Charles Dickens              Wordsworth Editions Ltd    English       768
Book2   C how to program    [Havey Deitel, Paul Deitel]  Prentice Hall              English       912
Book3   12 Rules for life   Jordan Peterson              Penguin                                    English       448
```

I would like to remove the `'['` as well as the `']'` from the Author column. I tried `.replace(,)` it didn't work and I also tried `.str.replace` it didn't work.

All the similar questions didn't help

Thank you

Comment: _it didn’t work_ Please elaborate. What exactly did you do, did it throw an error, what did the result look like, etc.? The formatting of the DataFrame output is off.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"auth":["Charles Dickens","[Havey Deitel, Paul Deitel]","Jordan Peterson"]})
df["auth"] = df["auth"].str.replace("[","").str.replace("]","")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the `list`. Just run this to see the output

```
data.Authors.to_dict()

Out[68]:
{'Book1': 'Charles Dickens',
 'Book2': ['Havey Deitel', 'Paul Deitel'],
 'Book3': 'Jordan Peterson'}
```

To convert them to string and strip `[]`, simply map `repr` and `replace` `[]'` with `''`

```
s = data.Authors.map(repr).str.replace("[\[\]\']", '')

Out[83]:
Book1              Charles Dickens
Book2    Havey Deitel, Paul Deitel
Book3              Jordan Peterson
Name: Authors, dtype: object

print(s.to_dict())

Out[87]:
{'Book1': 'Charles Dickens',
 'Book2': 'Havey Deitel, Paul Deitel',
 'Book3': 'Jordan Peterson'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
data.Authors.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x) if type(x) == list  else x)
```

output:

```
Book1              Charles Dickens
Book2    Havey Deitel, Paul Deitel
Book3              Jordan Peterson
```

```
data.Authors = data.Authors.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x) if type(x) == list  else x)
```

```
                   Title                    Authors                Publisher Language Pages
Book1  David Copperfield            Charles Dickens  Wordsworth Editions Ltd  English   768
Book2   C how to program  Havey Deitel, Paul Deitel            Prentice Hall  English   912
Book3  12 Rules for life            Jordan Peterson                  Penguin  English   448
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this -

   ```
   data['Authors'] = data['Authors'].apply(lambda x: ",".join(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
   data['Authors'] = data['Authors'].str.replace(",", " ")
   ```